# ASP DetailsView Rich Text Editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

Is there a way to use a Rich text(WYSIWYG) editor on the Update or Insert state of the ASP DetalsView? I've tried various options such as using a template field and adding a javascript plugin called tinyMCE. The problem with that though is that I can't bind data to it:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
<textarea ID="Solution" runat="server" class="myTextEditor" cols="20" 
name="tinymce" Text="<%# Bind('Solution') %>" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;">
</textarea>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

I get error message:

```
Error   2   Two-way binding is only supported for properties. 
'Text' is not a valid property on 'HtmlTextArea'
```

Comment: Have you tried binding to an Aps.net `TextBox` with `MultiLine=true`, that will render as a `textarea`.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you sir. If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept.